# Malformed object returned by query from a one-to-many Grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Consider these two Grails `domain` classes:

```
class Agreement implements Serializable {
    String code
    String branchCode
    ...

    static belongsTo = [agency: CollectingAgency]

    static mapping = {
        ...
    }
}

class CollectingAgency implements Serializable {
    String type
    String agencyClass
    ...

    static hasMany = [agreement: Agreement]

    static mapping = {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now when I perform `Agreement.findAll()` it creates a sql similar to this (using `loggingSql = true`):

```
select agreement0_.agency_id as agency4_67_1_, agreement0_.AGREH_CD as
    AGREH1_1_, agreement0_.AGREH_BRCHCD as AGREH2_1_,
    ...
    agreement0_.agency_id as agency4_66_0_,
                ^^^^^^^^^
    ...
from RVAGREHDROTB agreement0_
where agreement0_.agency_id=?
```

The statement will not execute because of the unknown column(`agency_id`). And I wonder where do it gets the `agency_id` column? I haven't mapped any column with such name.

And when I try to query from the other side using `CollectingAgency.findAll()`, it returns a malformed `Object`:

```
[
    {
        type: "0400300",
        agencyClass: "12",
        ...
        agreement: [
```

Yes, like that, with the `agreement` key having an opening square bracket `[` but no closing bracket `]`. Plus, the other properties of the table are not retrieved.

How can I achieve a query with a resulting object similar to these:

`Agreement.findAll()`:

```
[
    {
        code: "1212",
        branchCode: "a014s",
        ...
        agency: {
            type: "0400300",
            agencyClass: "12",
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        code: "1213",
        branchCode: "a014z",
        ...
        agency: {
            type: "0400300",
            agencyClass: "12",
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

and `CollectingAgency.findAll()`:

```
[
    {
        type: "0400300",
        agencyClass: "12",
        ...
        agreement: [
            {
                code: "1212",
                branchCode: "a014s",
                ...
            },
            {
                code: "1213",
                branchCode: "a014z",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Agreement class you have

```
static belongsTo = [agency: CollectingAgency]
```

which will create an 'agency' field in your class. the agency_id you see just maps your 'agency' field to the 'agency' column in the database.